# Why Weyl fermion in Weyl semimetals (WSM) have high mobility only at low temperature?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, temperature, dirac-equation, weyl-semimetal

I read several papers reporting high Weyl fermion with very high mobility in WSMs such as TaAs, NbAs, WTe2 and so on.
However, this high mobility looks like (=Weyl fermion) always appears at only low temperature.

This feature must be solved for application to electronics because our devices such as PC, smartphones have to work at room temperature, right?.

Why only at low temperature?

I guess it reflects the fact that Weyl fermion is low temperature excitation in WSM.
But I'm not sure what "low temperature" "excitation" is.
Please teach me something you know or I'm misunderstanding regarding this matter.

Comment: Not a formal answer. the reason is because , at low temperature , electrons in materials will mainly occupy on the zero mode(lowest Landau level) , where is the situation for electrons to behaviour like the Weyl fermions.